# Extending jQuery calls constructor on each method call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am painfully trying to extend jquery into an ES6 class and then transpile with Babel. Everything actually works except each time I call an inherited jQuery function, jQuery seems to call the constructor every time. This is evident in this fiddle. Also `trigger` seems to get called 4 times.

(transpiled code)
https://jsfiddle.net/w3bbzgrn/1/

This is the source code

```
class Popup extends jQuery.fn.init {
  constructor(t) {
    super(t);
    this.init(t);
    return this;
  }

    test(){
      this.trigger('test', 55)
      return this
    }
}

class Foo extends Popup{
  constructor(t){
    super(t)
    console.log("I get called")
      return this

  }
}

var t = $('<div>hi</div>')
var f = new Foo(t);
f.on('test', function(e,args){
  console.log(args)
})
f.appendTo('body').test().slideUp()
```

Comment: What exactly is higher level objective here? What problem are you trying to solve? This isn't how to create plugin for jQuery

Comment: Don't understand why you want to extend `jQuery.fn.init`

Comment: My intention is to provide something like a table generator, which has many of its own functions (like build, update, addRow, etc) but then inherit all jQuery functions like appendTo, slideUp, etc, which would be applied to the Table's wrapper element.

Comment: Furthermore, I want that class (Table, etc) to be inheritable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var stack = new Error().stack` to dump current call stack and see why the constructor gets called twice. See updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w3bbzgrn/3/

This prints to console:

```
PRINTING CALL STACK
Error
    at new Foo (VM149:90)
    at window.onload (VM149:102)
I get called
PRINTING CALL STACK
Error
    at new Foo (https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:90:15)
    at Foo.pushStack (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js:141:32)
    at Foo.jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) [as appendTo] (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js:5920:15)
    at window.onload (https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:106:3)
I get called
55
```

So, it's called twice but in two different situations:

1. The first time, it's called because of `var f = new Foo(t);`
2. The second time, when using `f.appendTo('body')`. It looks like it tries to create a copy of the element before appending it.

Maybe try googling something like ["jquery append creates duplicates"](https://www.google.cz/search?q=jquery+append+creates+duplicates).

Comment: I don't think it has to do with append. I think it is any jQuery call calls the constructor..